# Grails Spring Security Core logout message

Tags: grails, spring-security

I have an action which allows user to change his password. When everything goes well, I'd like to logout him and display a message that everything went well and now he needs to login using his new password.

I tried:

```
flash.message = "You may now login with your new password"
redirect (controller: 'logout')
```

Thing is that Logout controller makes redirection to:

```
redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl
```

And my flash message is no longer there when user is definitely logged out and back on main page. Any ideas how to make it work or maybe some workarounds?

Comment: Just curious, why are you logging them out? If I were using the system, I wouldn't expect to be logged out after changing my password.

Comment: No special reason. I'm just thinking it's better that way ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LogoutController is just there as a convenience. There's a filter that intercepts its redirect and performs the logout logic, so you can just redirect directly to that:

```
flash.message = "You may now login with your new password"
redirect uri: SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig.logout.filterProcessesUrl
```

Comment: Does this actually work?  When I've tried it, it doesn't.  If I redirect to `filterProcessesUrl` along with a `flash.message` the flash message is available to `filterProcessesUrl`, but it then redirects to `logout.afterLogoutUrl` and then loses any flash message in the 2nd redirect.  This 4 year old grails issue talks about it http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2336  To get this to work, I'd think that the `filterProcessesUrl` would need to see if it's received a `flash.message` and then set it again to make sure that it's propagated.

Comment: I've tried this suggestion, but it fails to reveal a flash.message. I'm using Grails 2.1.1

Comment: I've tried this with spring-security-core-2.0-RC2 and it doesn't work with it either.  'Debug says DEBUG logout.SimpleUrlLogoutSuccessHandler  - Using default Url: /login' and is ignoring the value set for grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = '/login/auth'.  The debug log shows the logout gets directed to login, then login gets directed to login/auth

Comment: Wayback for the GRAILS-2336 since jira.grails.org no longer works: http://web.archive.org/web/20130514120520/http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-2336

Answer (score 0):

Here is a work-around for this problem:

- Invalidate the session
- Setup the flash message
- Redirect to an empty page
- Then we run jQuery `delay` and `fadeutAndRemove` on the
  flash message div which then redirects to the logout controller

It's not perfect but it gets the message to the user and takes them back to the login page